# SO Newsletter: misleading "please cast your vote"

Tags: bug, moderator-election, newsletter

In the "2018 Community Moderator Election" section, the newsletter I received yesterday says:

> **Please cast your vote** by Mar 19!

However, as the same newsletter points out:

> The community moderator election is currently in the **nomination phase**.

which means no votes can be cast yet.

[image: screenshot]